# How to do automatic code alignment for all the code or a block of code in vi/vim?

Tags: linux, vim, vi, text-alignment

I want to know what's the quickest way to do automatic code alignment in vi/vim or a method to add something in `~/.vimrc` and then press a shortcut in vi/vim for making the code aligned/neat? Like I am using `:set cindent` in a `.c` code but it doesn't indent the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable automatic indenting — particularly for a C file — you can use something like this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set cindent
set autoindent
```

For more on those options, run `:help cindent` and `:help autoindent`.

To indent existing code in a file, you can use `=`, which will indent a selection (or indeed a whole file). One way to indent *all* the code in an *entire* file is to run

```
gg=G
```

or

```
1G=G
```

either of which will jump to the top of the file (`gg`, or `1G`), and then indent the code (`=`) from there to the end of the file (`G`). If you’d like to indent a particular block of code, you can visually select it and then run `=`; for example, to indent eight particular lines (including the one that the cursor is on), you could run

```
V7j=
```

which would enter linewise visual mode (`V`), selecting the current line, move down seven lines (`7j`), selecting those too, and then indent the selection (`=`).

Comment: How can I make use of the autoindent or autoalign in vimrc?

Comment: @MonaJalal  `autoindent, smartindent, cindent` there are different options, `:h them` for details. regarding "how to use", just `set xxx` in your vimrc.

Comment: @MonaJalal I updated the answer to mention how this can be set in a `.vimrc`, but yes, basically what Kent said above.

Comment: @BenKlein `gg=G` give ambiguous results. it  work for `int// function()` see this. https://pasteboard.co/H3s94AF.png